# Is that a way to marginTop a legend positioned on bottom of a Doughnut chartjs graph?

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I'm working with doughnut graphs using ChartJS and I'm having a bad time trying to create some kind of space between the graph and the legend.

That's my legend config:

```
plugins: {
  legend: {
    display: true,
    align: 'start',
    position: 'bottom',
  }
}
```

And that's the plugin I wrote to add more height to the legend:

```
const LegendMargin = {
  id: 'LegendMargin',
  beforeInit(chart, legend, options) {
    const fitValue = chart.legend.fit;

    chart.legend.fit = function fit() {
      fitValue.bind(chart.legend)();

      this.height += 40;
    }
  }
}
```

This plugin increased the height of the legend below the graph, but the text is still aligned to the top of the box, which doesn't fix the problem.

Can I somehow align the text to the bottom of the box or create some sort of margin/padding between the legend and the graph?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like the legend top position can be controlled using the `legend.top` property. But this property is managed by chart.js itself. So if you change it, is gonna be overwritten. So one hacky way to get around it is to use `Object.defineProperty` to intercept calls to `legend.top` like that:

```js
const LegendMarginPlugin = {
  id: 'LegendMarginPlugin',
  beforeInit(chart, legend, options) {
    const fitValue = chart.legend.fit;

    chart.legend.fit = function fit() {
      fitValue.bind(chart.legend)();

      let top;
      const marginTop = 30;

      Object.defineProperty(this, 'top', {
        get() {
          return top + marginTop;
        },
        set(v) {
          top = v;
        },
      });

      this.height += 40;
    };
  },
};
```

The value `30` and `40` here are example values that you might want to adjust for you needs.

Keep in mind that since this is not a public API it might break in future releases but it works for me on chart.js 3.9.0

The ideal is that they add support for the full [Padding](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/padding.html) object on `options.plugins.legend.labels.padding` config option so that you could use `padding.top` there. But currently only a single [numeric value works](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration)